# Topological properties that the real line does not have

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

The following question is kind of strange, but I would like to know what topological properties $\mathbb{R}$ (with the standard metric topology) does not posses?

I know this question sounds a bit broad. But I'm only looking for a partial list of topological properties that come to mind, which do not apply to the real line (standard metric topology ?).

As a starter, clearly, $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact. Any ideas of other common (or even more exotic) properties?

Thanks.

Comment: The real line is not compact

Comment: why on Earth was this so heavily downvoted?

Comment: @isomorphismes It was written a bit more poorly at start, but still I find some people here too agressive in that matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few, all easy to verify from their definitions. $\Bbb R$ is not:

- compact
- pseudocompact
- totally disconnected
- zero-dimensional
- extremally disconnected
- non-Archimedeanly metrizable (= ultrametrizable)
- scattered
- irreducible (= hyper-connected)

(If I think of more later, I’ll add them.)

Comment: Thank you very much! At last someone here gives me a descent answer. Hope the other users which said that the question is too broad will take an example from you :)

Comment: @Aviv: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The most important topological properties are:

- Separation properties, known sometimes as $T_0$, $T_1$, $T_2$, etc. $\Bbb R$ fulfills all of them because it is a metric space.
- Connection: $\Bbb R$ is connected, path-connected and simply connected.
- Compactness: $\Bbb R$ is not compact because it is a not bounded metric space, but it is locally compact.
- Countability axioms: $\Bbb R$ fulfills both essentialy because $\Bbb Q$ is dense and countable.

To sum up, the only "important" property that $\Bbb R$ does not have is compactness.

Of course, I'm assuming you are talking about $\Bbb R$ with the *usual* topology.

Comment: Did you miss the word "not"?

Comment: No, but I decided to enumerate the most important properties to say which of them are fulfilled by $\Bbb R$ and which are not.

Comment: The Wikipedia page [topological property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_property) enumerates even more properties. One can see for oneself which ones $\mathbb{R}$ lacks.